# Copying of type struct '' memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity, storage, memory

I can't figure out how to initial this data for the life of me. I have 2 structs which looks like so:

```
struct UserVotes {
   address userAddress;
   VoteOptionAmounts[] votes;
}

struct VoteInfo {
    uint256[] totalVotes;
    UserVotes[] userVotes;
    VoteChoices[] voteChoices;
}
```

I'm trying to initialize User Votes for a paticular user:

Attempt 1:

```
UserVotes memory newVote = UserVotes(account, new VoteOptionAmounts[](0));
proposal.voteInfo.userVotes.push(newVote);
```

Attempt 2:

```
VoteOptionAmounts[] storage userOptionAmounts = new VoteOptionAmounts[](0);
proposal.voteInfo.userVotes.push(UserVotes(account,  userOptionAmounts));
```

Attempt 3:

```
proposal.voteInfo.userVotes.push(UserVotes(account,  [VoteOptionAmounts(voteOptions[i].supportOption, optionWeight)]));
```

Nothing seems to work everything returns:

> Copying of type struct VoteOptionAmounts memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can just push back an empty slot first;

```
uint256 userVotesIndex = proposal.voteInfo.userVotes.length; 
proposal.voteInfo.userVotes.push();
UserVotes storage userVote = proposal.voteInfo.userVotes[userVotesIndex];
```